# Manipulating HTML-Code in Python3

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, web

I'm trying to manipulate a HTML-File and remove a *div* with a certain id-Tag, using Python3.

Is there a more elegant way to manipulate or remove this container than a mix of *for*-Loops and *regex*?

I know, there is the HTMLParser module, but I'm not sure if this will help me (it finds the corresponding tags, but how to remove those and the contents?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and css/xpath queries.

For example, with this html:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Some text in a p.</p>
    <div class="go-away">Some text in a div.</div>
    <div><p>Some text in a p in a div</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can read that in, remove the div with class "go-away", and output the result with:

```python
import lxml.html

html = lxml.html.fromstring(html_txt)
go_away = html.cssselect('.go-away')[0] # Or with suitable xpath
go_away.getparent().remove(go_away)

lxml.html.tostring(html) # Or lxml.html.tostring(html).decode("utf-8") to get a string
```

Comment: Thanks, **lxml** was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

While I can't stress this enough

### DON'T PARSE HTML WITH REGEX!!

here's how I'd do it with regex.

```
from re import sub
new_html = sub('<div class=(\'go-away\'|"go-away")>.*?</div>', '', html)
```

Even though I think that should be ok, you should never ever use regex to parse anything. More often than anything it creates odd, hard-to-debug issues. It'll create more work for you than you started with. **Don't parse with regex.**

Comment: Yes, indeed. Don't do it. [Or you may go mad.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/675568)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! And this is the exact reason why I try to avoid doing it with regex. It simply sucks because no matter what you do, things break so much quicker with regex.

Comment: There are times for regex and there are times when it's not appropriate, it's absolutely brilliant for high volumes of predictable data. :)